# TabBarView causes contents of FutureBuilder to disappear

Tags: flutter, dart

The issue I am currently experiencing can be seen in this gif:

[image]

When I select "Enrolled" tab and then go back to "All Grades" tab, all of the contents in "All Grades" tab disappears. The contents of "All Grades" tab is displayed from a `FutureBuilder` widget.

Here is the code:

```
class Grades extends StatefulWidget
{
  @override
  _Grades createState() => _Grades();
}

class _Grades extends State<Grades> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Grades>
{
  void initState()
  {
    getCategoriesInFuture = getAllCategories();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    super.build(context);

      return DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child:
        Scaffold(
        appBar:
          AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: "All Grades"),
                Tab(text: "Enrolled"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        body:
          TabBarView(children: [
            Container(
                child:
                FutureBuilder<List<GradesData>>(
                    future: getCategoriesInFuture,
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<GradesData>> snapshot)
                    {
                      if(snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Column(
                            children: gradesButtonBuilder(snapshot.data)
                        );
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        return Center(
                          child:
                          SizedBox(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            width: 60,
                            height: 60,
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    }
                )
            ),
            Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
          ],)
        ),
      );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of a `TabView` is re-rendered each time you change the tab. To prevent so, the Widget of your `TabView` must implements `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` and return `true` in the `wantKeepAlive` method like this `@override bool get wantKeepAlive => true;`

Answer (score 0):

getCategoriesInFuture = getAllCategories () initstate accessed one time. If you put it under the build context, it will fix. Or you send requests every time the tabbar changes; Every time you change a tab, the buildcontext is loaded from the beginning.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
  super.build(context);
  ---->>>  getCategoriesInFuture = getAllCategories();
 ..........
 .......
  ....
```

Comment: From what I know, `build()` gets called more than once. Won't it be considered bad practice if I call a `future` from within `build()`?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the `FutureBuilder<List<GradesData>>` to another `StatefulWidget` which implements `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`

```
    class Grades extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _Grades createState() => _Grades();
    }

    class _Grades extends State<Grades> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Grades> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        super.build(context);

        return DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                bottom: TabBar(
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: "All Grades"),
                    Tab(text: "Enrolled"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              body: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  GradesList(),
                  Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                ],
              )),
        );
      }

      @override
      bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
    }

    class GradesList extends StatefulWidget {
      GradesList({Key key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _GradesListState createState() => _GradesListState();
    }

    class _GradesListState extends State<GradesList>
        with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
      @override
      void initState() {
        getCategoriesInFuture = getAllCategories();

        super.initState();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        super.build(context);
        return Container(
            child: FutureBuilder<List<GradesData>>(
                future: getCategoriesInFuture,
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<List<GradesData>> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Column(children: gradesButtonBuilder(snapshot.data));
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        width: 60,
                        height: 60,
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }));
      }

      @override
      bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
    }
```